# Fetch Latt and lon geo location data - how do I determine N/S/E/W and add them to the end

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which grabs the latt and longitude for london

And returns me the results 51.49742 / -0.14159

Here's my JSFiddle
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/n8ebjyL3/9/)

here was the original

```
fetch('https://geocode.xyz/london?json=1')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
  response.json().then(data => {
  fbjson = data;
  var latt = fbjson.alt.loc.latt;
  
  var longt =fbjson.alt.loc.longt;
  var stringerr = latt + " / " + longt
      $div1_.textContent = stringerr;
    });
  } else $div1_.textContent = 'Network response was not ok.';
})
.catch(error =>
$div1_.textContent = 'Fetch error: ' + error
);
```

now where I am stuck is I am trying to determine n/s for latt and e/w for longt and display the result simaler to Google like this

```
googles results = 51.5074° N, 0.1278° W
```

I would like

```
51.5074° N / 0.1278° W
```

How can I determine and add
° W or others accordingly to the long and latt

Comment: I would assume a negative lat is E, and a negative long is S?

Comment: also i dont have to state i have reaserched i have already stated i have been reaserching and creating my code i would get this far without any reasearch

Comment: could u help and point me in the direction to using the if statments <0

Comment: see andrea this is where u dont think properly a person may reaserch and find info close to helping but then not understand the actual statments before him and then came here looking for help and examples

Comment: thanks for the edits giys and thanks evolutionxbox u awkened my brain when i needed it and just managed to rustle th if statment together thanks so much

Comment: Your code needs to be included in your question, not externally on a fiddle.  Your lack of included code is why you are getting close and down votes.  Put your code here.  Explain what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so i created a new jsfiddle an focused on my if statments only

i managed to anser my own questions with this code

```
      if (latt > 0) {
      alert('posotive')
      } else {
      alert('negative')
      }
```

i then altered it to my needs within my script

its a shame people had to accuse me of no reasrch i just needed a chat and some help but tremdous thanks to the first commenter evolutionxbox

so first for the code so i dont upset down voters

```
fetch('https://geocode.xyz/london?json=1')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
  response.json().then(data => {
  fbjson = data;
  var latt = fbjson.alt.loc.latt;
  
  var longt =fbjson.alt.loc.longt;
  
   if (latt > 0) {latt = latt +  " ° N";} else {latt = latt + " ° S"

}

   if (longt > 0) {
  longt = longt +  " ° E";
  } else {
  longt = longt + " ° W"

 }

var stringerr = latt + " / " + longt
    $div1_.textContent = stringerr;
  });
} else $div1_.textContent = 'Network response was not ok.';
})
.catch(error =>
$div1_.textContent = 'Fetch error: ' + error
);
```

here is the working jsfiddle for anyone needing visual help like i often do

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8ebjyL3/23/)